# running a loop if the user press 'y' or 'Y'

Tags: c

I am unable to execute the do while for until 'y' or 'Y' is pressed. Please find the code which i written::
    The problem is when am executing this program , First time its showing menu item and processing correctly and its waiting to get the input from user. And the second time also its showing menu correctly but its not waiting for the user to get the input. Instead its quit the execution. Please provide the solution to overcome this solution

### C Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>


void display_menu(void);


void display_menu()
{
    char c='y';
    printf("\n This is Menu for Single Linkd List");
    do
    {   
        printf("\n Press 1 for Create Link List ");
        printf("\n Press 2 for Insert Node");
        printf("\n Press 3 for Delete the entire list");
        printf("\n Press 4 for Delete the Node");
        printf("\n Press 5 for Reverse the List");
        printf("\n Press 6 for Display the List");
        printf("\n Press 7 for Display the Node");
        printf("\n Press 'y' or 'Y' for Display the Menu again \n");
        if(c=='\n')
            c='\0';
        scanf("%c",&c);//getchar();
        printf("c=%c", c);
    }while(c=='y' || c=='Y');

}



int main()
{


    display_menu();

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Execution output:

```
[sambath@localhost exercise]$ ./a.out

This is Menu for Single Linkd List
Press 1 for Create Link List
Press 2 for Insert Node
Press 3 for Delete the entire list
Press 4 for Delete the Node
Press 5 for Reverse the List
Press 6 for Display the List
Press 7 for Display the Node
Press 'y' or 'Y' for Display the Menu again
y
c=y
Press 1 for Create Link List
Press 2 for Insert Node
Press 3 for Delete the entire list
Press 4 for Delete the Node
Press 5 for Reverse the List
Press 6 for Display the List
Press 7 for Display the Node
Press 'y' or 'Y' for Display the Menu again
c=
[sambath@localhost exercise]$
```

---

Comment: This line `if(c=='\n') c='\0';` hides all the info you need.

Comment: hmmm... why do you have getchar commented out... seems that might work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

Use:

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

The leading space tells scanf() to skip residual whitespace characters (including '\n') before reading the next character.

Comment: It's working fine thanks and am able to run n number of times until y is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account new line characters etc.

So the `scanf` should just eat them

Answer (score 1):

The conversion specifier `"%c"` does not ignore whitespace. So when you type "Y" both the "Y" and the "" get assigned to `c`.

You have several options:

1. use `fgets()` for obtaining user input
2. ignore whitespace
3. use a 1-char string (`char onechar[2];`) and the conversion specifier `"%1s"` to have `scanf()` automatically ignore leading whitespace

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // to use tolower()


void display_menu(void);


void display_menu()
{
 char c;

  /* char c = 'y'; You don't need to set it equal to y. 
     The do-while loop will run at least one time regardless of you condition */

  printf("This is Menu for Single Linkd List:\n");

 do
 {
    printf("Press 1 for Create Link List \n");
    printf("Press 2 for Insert Node\n");
    printf("Press 3 for Delete the entire list\n");
    printf("Press 4 for Delete the Node\n");
    printf("Press 5 for Reverse the List\n");
    printf("Press 6 for Display the List\n");
    printf("Press 7 for Display the Node\n");
    printf("Press 'y' or 'Y' for Display the Menu again \n");

    scanf(" %c",&c);
    c = tolower(c); //simplifies you while condition.
 }while( c == 'y');

}



int main()
{
 display_menu();

 return 0;
}
```